# Why operation system has so big impact on JDK size per system?

Tags: java

I was reading about JDK 10 early-access builds and I noticed that there are huge differences between sizes of JDK on:

- Windows 341 MB
- MacOS 343 MB
- Linux 287 MB
- Solaris Spark 207 MB

What are the reasons, except differences resulting from differences of operations system?

For example, Windows JDK contains some tools which Solaris does not contain or maybe the size of JDK for some system is smaller because some of the systems already contain some tools?